# Remove search from address bar from Firefox

Tags: firefox, address-bar

Lately my cursor has been jumping from a site I'm typing on up to the address bar to begin a search. It never used to do this. Is there a way to disable search from the address bar. It's very annoying to be in the middle of typing something only to find it all typed up in the address bar.

Comment: You're probably accidentally pressing Ctrl+K