# How do I disable Search from Address Bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, search, address-bar

I see this question has been asked (only once?) back in 2015 (and there was no answer).

[Remove search from address bar from Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/973085/remove-search-from-address-bar-from-firefox)

I seem to remember, when using an old version of Firefox (like version 2.x) that you could disable search from the address bar.  So when you typed in garbage, or you mis-typed a URL in the address bar, the browser didn't automatically perform a google search on what you typed.  Is there no setting for this on FF today?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable searching and domain guessing from the Firefox Address Bar, while keeping other features?](https://superuser.com/questions/389136/how-can-i-disable-searching-and-domain-guessing-from-the-firefox-address-bar-wh)

Answer (score 11):

This [Reddit thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/9ex9ce/disable_search_in_awesome_bar/) may be of use.

First type `about:config` in the address bar, and then follow these steps:

> Set both `keyword.enabled` and `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` to `false`. This will ensure that anything you type will be treated as a domain name, not potentially as a search request, and that the domain name will be exactly as you typed it.
>
> You may also want to set `browser.urlbar.suggest.searches` to `false` to ensure that partially typed URLs don't ever get sent off to a search engine too.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Load up the `live headers` addon, and watch it while you type into the address bar.

Comment: I can vouch that this process worked for me in FF 77.0.1. If relevant, I also have `browser.urlbar.suggest.searches` set to `false`.

Comment: For me setting `keyword.enabled` to `false` was enough.